# How to parse user input as a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a calculator program in my Python, following a tutorial. Here is my code:

```
print ("This is a calculator program, press Enter to continue")
a = input()

while a == "":
    print("Enter 1 for option 1 which adds")
    print("Enter 2 for option 2 which subtracts")
    print("Enter 3 for option 3 which multiply")
    print("Enter 4 for option 4 which divides")
    print("Enter 5 for option 5 which quits",)

    Option = input("Enter an option number:")
    int(Option)

    if Option == 1:
        Number1 = input("Enter number 1")
        Number2 = input("Enter number 2")
        int(Number1,Number2)
        print(Result = Number1 + Number2)

    if Option == 2:
        Number1 = input("Enter number 1")
        Number2 = input("Enter number 2")
        int(Number1,Number2)
        print(Result = Number1 - Number2)

    if Option == 3:
        Number1 = input("Enter number 1")
        Number2 = input("Enter number 2")
        int(Number1,Number2)
        print(Result = Number1 * Number2)

    if Option == 4:
        Number1 = input("Enter number 1")
        Number2 = input("Enter number 2")
        int(Number1,Number2)
        print(Result = Number1 / Number2)

    if Option == 5:
        break
```

It is very basic, it gets up to the point of printing all the option numbers and then asks me to pick one. So I enter "1" as a string, parsing it to an integer 1. However it doesn't go straight to option 1 and instead loops again which is fine I will sort that out later. But again it doesn't go to any option when I enter 1-5. I think I typed in the wrong code to parse it or something?

Comment: your not saving out the int function. try `you_var =int(Number1,Number2)`

Comment: `a = input()` should be inside the while loop, and also instead of `print(Result = Number1 + Number2)` you should `print(Number1 + Number2)` (similarly for the other options)

Comment: You should *really* use a better title. Almost every beginner in Python *just* started learning, but that doesn't mean that your question would be useful to them.

Comment: also `Number1 = int(input(...))`

Comment: I believe your also looking for `raw_input()`

Comment: @agconti the OP seems to be using Python3, where it's `input`, not `raw_input` AFAIK

Comment: I think your main problem is the comparison `Option = 1`. Option will be a `str` and 1 is an `int`. It'll always return false.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you take a look at the guidelines for asking a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and consider editing your title to be more meaningful. We look forward to you contributing to the community!

Comment: +1 for a very much improved question after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` converts the input to a *string*, so if you need to read an `int`, you have to cast it.

In the `if` condition, you could cast the `input()` result (a string) to `int`:

```
Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1"))
```

then create a variable, let's say `result` and assign it the sum of the numbers:

```
result = Number1 + Number2
```

and finally print the result

```
print "Result = " + str(result)
```

The final code should look like this:

```
print ("This is a calculator program, press Enter to continue")
a = input()

while a == "":
    print
    print("Enter 1 for option 1 which adds")
    print("Enter 2 for option 2 which subtracts")
    print("Enter 3 for option 3 which multiply")
    print("Enter 4 for option 4 which divides")
    print("Enter 5 for option 5 which quits",)

    Option = input("Enter an option number:")

    if Option == 1:
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1"))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2"))
        result = Number1 + Number2
        print "Result = " + str(result) # To print you have to cast to `str`

    elif Option == 2:
        ...
    elif Option == 3:
        ...
    elif Option == 4:
        ...
    else:
        break
```

**Notes:**

- You could use an `if-elif-else` as the structure, so if `Option == 1`, the following conditions won't be checked.
- I would also recommend you to follow [Python naming convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Your variable `Number1` should be called `number1` and so on.

Comment: There is no `raw_input` in Python 3, which OP seems to be using. Python 3 `input` behaves like Python 2 `raw_input`, and there is no Python 3 equivalent of Python 2's `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Result of [input](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function is a `string`, you need to convert it to `int`, using `int` type .

```
>>> foo = "3"
>>> foo
'3'
>>> int(foo)
3
```

Your misconception might come from that python is a dynamically typed language. But remember that despite variables themselves are untyped, variable values have types.

```
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(int(foo))
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look more like this:

```
print("This is a calculator program. Press Enter to continue.")

while True:
    _ = input()
    print("Enter 1 for option 1 which adds")
    print("Enter 2 for option 2 which subtracts")
    print("Enter 3 for option 3 which multiply")
    print("Enter 4 for option 4 which divides")
    print("Enter 5 for option 5 which quits")

    option = int(input("Enter an option number: "))

    if option == 5:
        break
    else:
        number1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
        number2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
        if option == 1:
            result = number1 + number2
        elif option == 2:
            result = number1 - number2
        elif option == 3:
            result = number1 * number2
        elif option == 4:
            result = number1 / number2
        print(result)
```

Salient points:

- You aren't doing anything with `a`. So I got rid of it, and put a call to `input` that stores its result in `_`, which is the standard name for a variable whose value you don't care about.
- You must explicitly convert `option` to an `int`. Python will not implicitly convert for you, and so `'1' != 1`.
- You cannot convert to an `int` in-place - writing `int(number1)` does nothing. You must write `number1 = int(number1)` or similar.
- You cannot convert multiple strings to an `int` in a single statement of the form `int(number1, number2)`. What you're actually doing here is calling `int(x, base)`, where you convert `x` into an `int`, interpreted as being in base `base`.
- I refactored your `if` statements to be more concise
- Variable names are typically lowercase in Python.
- You cannot assign to a variable inside a print statement.

Comment: Hey do you know where you said Option = int(input("Enter an option number:")), is it possible to do it like this Option = input("Enter an option number") /newline int(Option)? I forgot to put that in my orignal post, the one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

that code posted contains several errors, below is the corrected code:

```
print ("This is a calculator program, press Enter to continue")
a = input()

while a == "":
    print("Enter 1 for option 1 which adds")
    print("Enter 2 for option 2 which subtracts")
    print("Enter 3 for option 3 which multiply")
    print("Enter 4 for option 4 which divides")
    print("Enter 5 for option 5 which quits",)

    Option = int(input("Enter an option number:"))

    if Option == 1:
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1"))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2"))
        # int(Number1,Number2)
        Result = Number1 + Number2

    if Option == 2:
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1"))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2"))
        # int(Number1,Number2)
        Result = Number1 - Number2

    if Option == 3:
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1"))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2"))
        # int(Number1,Number2)
        Result = Number1 * Number2

    if Option == 4:
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1"))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2"))
        # int(Number1,Number2)
        Result = Number1 / Number2

    print(Result)

    if Option == 5:
        break
```

Comment: Hey do you know where you said Option = int(input("Enter an option number:")), is it possible to do it like this Option = input("Enter an option number") /newline int(Option)?

Comment: @user3216729, yes but you need to do `Option=int(Option)`

Comment: ah right ty, I come from C# so thats why I would do it like that. I tend to go for 1 or 2 more lines instead of doing all in one line for me personally, jsut helps me look over it.Thanks!

Comment: @user3216729, you could upvote or accept it if you like this answer. ;)

Comment: C# is the only language I know so far, and in C# I would do it this way Console.Write("Enter an option number") /newline string option = Console.ReadLine() /newline optionnumber = int.Parse(option). Is an input() just the same as a Console.Write()/Console.WriteLine()? It doesnt let me upvote :/

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code.

```
_ = input("This is a calculator program, press Enter to continue")
print ("""Enter 1 for option 1 which adds
          Enter 2 for option 2 which subtracts
          Enter 3 for option 3 which multiplies
          Enter 4 for option 4 which divides
          Enter 5 for option 5 which quits""")
while True:
    Option = input("Enter an option number: ")

    if Option == '1':
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
        print("The Result is {0}".format(Number1 + Number2))

    elif Option == '2':
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
        print("The Result is {0}".format(Number1 - Number2))

    elif Option == '3':
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
        print("The Result is {0}".format(Number1 * Number2))

    elif Option == '4':
        Number1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
        Number2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
        print("The Result is {0}".format(Number1 / Number2))

    else:
        break
```

Notes:

1. Triple quote syntax is good for long multiline strings.
2. The pythonic way of formatting a printed string is the [str.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) method.

Good luck learning!