# When I run my code, I get an error which states TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

This is my code. I can input, but when I press enter, I get the error.

```
import math
x = 13
age = input("Please input your age.")
if x < age:
    print("Nice, you can use this website!")

if x > age:
    print("Sorry, you are too young")
    
if x == age:
    print("Nice, you can use this website!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse user input as a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262772/how-to-parse-user-input-as-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a `str`, not an `int`.

```
...
age = int(input("Please input your age"))
...
```

Also, consider consolidating your `if` statements like so:

```
if x <= age:
    print("Nice, you can use this website!")
else:
    print("Sorry, you are too young")
```